# How do you make a header on an HTML page based on user input from a previous page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, user-input

I am very new to HTML, css, jQuery, javascript, etc. and on a website I am making, I want to take the user's input and make that the header of another page of my website. I don't understand how to transfer that information from one HTML page to another.

Comment: Can you show us what you did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use local storage .

To set:

```
var UserInput=$('#txtBoxID').val();
localStorage.setItem(yourkey,UserInput);
```

To get the value on other page:

```
 var header = localStorage.getItem(yourkey);
 $('#YourHeaderHtmlID').val(header );
```

Note that you all do this inside document ready.

```
$(function() {

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering where these go? Is the "var header = localStorage.getItem(yourkey);
 $('#YourHeaderHtmlID').val(header );" in the body section?

Comment: Glad to help. upvote and accept answer if it's help . Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a javacript function to set cookie with the header name before moving to the next page
if it is anchor tag

```
<a href="nextpage.html" onclick="setHeaderName()"/>
```

In the next page, you can get the cookie using script and call funciton inside the title

```
<head><title><script>callCookieHeaderValue()</script></title></head>

callCookieHeaderValue() is the function you can write to return the cookie value
```